# How automatically resize the text size according to window size in pyqt qtdesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I want to automatically resize the `Q-label` text size according to window size.
In python `qt-designer`.

For example, if window size is max, `Q-label` text size is big and if window size is min, `Q-label` text size is small

How can I solve?

Comment: Use a layout to place the QLabel in the window

Comment: It is not possible to do this in qt designer. You will have to write the code yourself and adjust the font-size in the `resizeEvent`.